# How to add Modal Popup in Angularjs 2

Tags: angular

How to import and show modal popup in Angularjs 2 also i want to show tr value in popup.

I am new from Angularjs. Please guide me how to implement this

**`environment_app.component.ts`**

```
import {Component} from "angular2/core";

@Component({
   selector: 'my-app',
   templateUrl: 'app/hello.component.html'
})

export class AppComponent {
     constructor() {     

     }
     removeItem(index){
        this.itemList.splice(index, 1);
     }

    IsHidden= false;
    onSelect(item){
        item.IsHidden = !item.IsHidden;
    }

}
```

**`environment_main.ts`**

```
import {bootstrap} from "angular2/platform/browser"
import {AppComponent} from "./environment_app.component"

bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

**`html`**

**

```
<div class="container">
<br><br><br>
<h2>Customer Order Report</h2>
<table class="table table-striped" *ngIf="itemList.length">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="text-center">S.No</th>
        <th class="text-center">Name</th>
        <th class="text-center">Email</th>
        <th class="text-center">City</th>
        <th class="text-center">Action</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="#item of itemList; #i = index">
        <td class="text-center">{{i+1}}</td>
        <td class="text-center">{{item.name}}</td>
        <td class="text-center">{{item.email}}</td>
        <td class="text-center">{{item.city}}</td>
        <td class="text-center"><span (click)="removeItem($index)" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove pointer"></span>
        <span>Edit</span></td>
      </tr>     
    </tbody>
  </table>
    <div *ngIf="!itemList.length" class="nodata"> No Data Available........</div>
</div>
```

How to implement this ?

Can you please explain it also

Answer (score 0):

You can use third party popup like ngPrime or angular2 material for it. You can read their README.md for details or visit their website

Comment: No actually i want bootstrub modal popup

Comment: There is modal from bootstrap built in angular which u can use

Comment: Can you please tell me how to use i am now to Angular js